# I am confused by an exercise in C++ Primer (Flow Execution)

Tags: c++, console-application

Hello I am currently trying to work out this bit of code. I think I have cracked it but the one bit I am struggling with is how it is detecting each and every number that I input for it to say how many times it reads each number.

```
int main()
{
    int currentValue = 0, value = 0;
    int count = 1;


    if (cin >> currentValue) //Get first number to process from user
    {
        while (cin >> value) //Get subsequent numbers
        {
            if (value == currentValue) //If subsequent numbers are the first as the first number entered
            {
                ++count; //Add to count for how many there are
            }

            else //if not
            {
                cout << currentValue << " occurs " << count << " times" << endl;

                currentValue = value; //Remember the new value
                count = 1; //Reset counter
            }
        }

        //Prints for the value in the file
        cout << currentValue << " occurs " << count << " times" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am unsure on how the if statement and the while statement are working together and what their relationship is. Is what happening is that the if statement reads the first number then the while statement reads the latter numbers?

Comment: It is always good to learn how to use the debugger (single-step, line by line) so that you see the flow for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is as you said. The if statement tries to read into `currentValue` and the while tries to read into `value`. The if statement is executed first, and then the while is executed, well, while the condition holds. They have no dependencies between them.